# WiFi randomly dies on fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: wireless

My WiFi randomly cuts out and stays dead until I reboot. This seems to happen after about 5 or 10 minutes. I've tried all the many dozens of solutions posted on this forum for this, but to no avail.

When I boot in Windows, the WiFi works fine. Funny thing is that I have Linux versions that are one and two decades old, and they work fine. I have WiFi sleep turned off, as well as a bunch of other things.

I'm getting a lot of these errors when this happens. It looks like there might be a problem with the way DMA is being attempted:

```
ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMA
ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'd really like to be up and running with a modern version of Linux as the supplied compilers and other things could be much improved.

Comment: Try a 19.04 (or soon 19.10) LiveUSB. If the problem still occurs on a recent release of Ubuntu, then please file a bug report. If it turns out that the problem is fixed in recent releases of Ubuntu, then please file a different bug report to backport the fix to older releases.

Comment: Problem still persists in 19.04.  It seems like bug report should have already been submitted since there are hundreds of solutions to this problem posted out there (none of which have worked for me so far). But I will look into the bug report.  I'll also try regressing versions until I get one that works, but these version downloads take a long time.

Comment: It might be productive to search Launchpad.net for an existing bug report before perhaps duplicating prior efforts. "[H]undreds of solutions" often means multiple causes (multiple bugs). Developers can fix only the bugs that they can reliably reproduce. Your demonstration of non-defective hardware is a solid start.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu 18.04.3](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso) is out, you can download and try it to see if your wifi works via [LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) without installing into your hard drive.

If not, you can still try LiveCD of [Ubuntu 16.04.6](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso) which is LTS and still supported at the moment.

Comment: I upgraded to 19.04.  I like it much better because it can automatically decrypt keys on login and has better details in the GUI.  However, I am still having the same problem with random disconnects that require a hard reboot.

Comment: @onehit pick If your .iso files downloads take a long time, you can try  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors to find a close maybe fast CD mirror

Comment: update: I have a static IP, power saving modes off, ipv6 disabled, and several "safe" measures, but it's still disconnecting.  Worse, it requires a hard reboot, and no netmanager restarts or ifdown/up helps.  The problem persists across several different access points and different computers, but windows mode works fine.  I'm thinking I'm done with this.  The compiler and everything else is great, but the wireless networking is at the "toy" level, at best.

Comment: @onehit pick Have you tried Ubuntu 16.04.6 LiveCD/LiveUSB?

Comment: not yet.  I tried going from 18.04 to 19.04.  I'll try older versions next.  I do normally have bluetooth off, but I notice that when I turn bluetooth on and connect to a device, the wifi immediately crawls to a halt (not disconnecting, however).  Perhaps the two problems are related?

Comment: @onehit pick bluetooth and wifi are often combined in a single chip inside laptops. Are you using a laptop? If true, what is the brand and model number? IMO you should google your_laptop_model+wifi+ubuntu to see info.